# Python - 2 df with same structure add together in 3rd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just messing around with some football data and I essentially want to add 2 dataframes together on a couple columns.

Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'PlayerID': [1, 2], 'Name': ['Tyreek', 'Amari'], 'Targets': [15, 16], 'Receptions': [11, 13]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'PlayerID': [1, 2], 'Name': ['Tyreek', 'Amari'], 'Targets': [4, 5], 'Receptions': [3,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

desired output
[PlayerID|Name|Targets|Receptions]
[    1   |Tyreek|  19 | 14]
[    2   |Amari |  21 | 16]
```

Both dataframes have the same columns but are from different weeks of the season. I've tried merge/concat/add but that just adds weeks separately. I would like to create a season to date dataframe that just adds the latest week. For example Tyreek Hill had 15 targets in week one and 4 targets in week 2, so the season to date dataframe should show 19 targets.

Comment: Please provide your data frames/code as text and not as images

Comment: in addition, could you add the desired result as a text table?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df1.set_index(['PlayerID', 'Name']).add(df2.set_index(['PlayerID', 'Name'])).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   PlayerID    Name  Targets  Receptions
0         1  Tyreek       19          14
1         2   Amari       21          16
```